# Dealing with read no parse error for lists

Tags: parsing, haskell, option-type

Hello can someone please explain me how can you deal with failed computations (in our case parsings) in Haskell when performed in a list,retrieving the successful elements?

The error i get is 
`main: Prelude.read: no parse` and that stops all the list from being processed

I am using a  `forM` over a collection of `Text` , and for each element i am using a
 `read::String->Double` for the result value.

Currently the parsing fails at the first element and i can not parse the remaining elements.How can i make single elements "fail-able" but still get partial results ( for the elements of the list that could be parsed) ?

**Example** :
**Input**:   `["asta","1.23","2.44"]`
  **Desired Output**:`[1.23,2.44]`

```
import qualified Data.Text as T

parseDfile::[T.Text]->IO [Maybe Double]
    parseDfile []=do
        return  [Nothing]
    parseDfile lines = forM lines $ \line ->
                          do   
                          Prelude.putStrLn ("line value:"++(T.unpack line))
                          let value = (read::String->Double) . T.unpack $ //fails here  for first element 
                          print .show $ value
                          return (Just value)
```

**P.S**
Do i have to define a method using the `Maybe` monad separately only for that one line of code ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Text.Read` library also has a function called `readMaybe` that returns a `Maybe a` instead of just an `a` like `read` does.

In the case that you're not sure whether or not a string can be parsed, you clearly want a `Maybe a`. Now you need to deal with the `Maybe` though, however the `Maybe` monad has tons of functions that do exactly what you need.

For more complicated parsing you could look into the Haskell ParseLib which is really good. However it might be a little overkill if you're not trying to parse more than your example.